# Making new cell default to 1 line in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica 8 when you open a new cell it gives that cell 2 lines by default. I find this terribly annoying and wish it would just opened 1 line. I've googled a bunch, checked out reference.wolfram.com, and looked through the Format>Option Inspector with no luck.

Comment: I only get this when I use return/enter to create the cell, which I think makes sense.  Regular (alphanumeric) characters create a cell with a single line.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense too. Make it a full answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not usually true.

If you position your cursor to insert a Cell and start typing, no extra line is inserted.

Although (I must confess), I tend to start typing in a cell with an <kbd>Enter</kbd> `:D`